# Cannot compile with importing of class which is in the dependency jar file

Tags: java, json

I want to use JSON functionality in Java. For those, I downloaded https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107 file and try compile using:

```
javac -cp ".:/deps/json-20140107.jar" MyClass.java
```

but I receive the error:

```
package org.json does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works great for me:

javac -cp ./json.jar MyClass.java

Not sure why you have that ":" there.